# selecting text of a page in selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I'm a relative beginner in python and selenium and am facing an issue.
Using Selenium, I click on a link that by default opens in a new tab and I want to print all the text of the new page in my termianal, How do I accomplish this? please share your code.
Attaching a snippet of the page source.

```
<html><head><script src="chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/prompt.js"></script></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">                                   
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    return 0;
}
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to print the code enclosed in the 'pre' tag in my terminal.

Comment: Welcome to SO in order for people to answer your questions please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example see the help guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: try using [request-html](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/)

Comment: Please provide full html so that it helps reproduce your problem

Comment: @TekNath this is the entire html, the webpage only shows the submitted c++ code of the user.

Answer (score 0):

As you say if your page only contains HTML that you have provided, you can do the following.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver= webdriver.Chrome("chromedriverr")

driver.get("your_test_site_url")

print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/pre").text)
```

When you run the program you get following output in terminal.

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    return 0;
}
```